# how to increase image size on mouse over function

Tags: html, easeljs

Hello every one I am new to html5.I have written a code in which I have use easelJS library.I have loaded an image and I want to try different mouse events.I have loaded an image on the canvas and it is working fine but I want my image to get enlarge when i put mouse over it.But I dont know why it is not working.Can any one please guide me what have I missed here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="EaselJS/lib/easel.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas;
var stage;
var img , pic;
var update =true;
function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    stage = new Stage(canvas);
        img = new Image();
    img.src = "picture.png";
    img.onload = setimage;

}
function setimage(event){
  pic = new Bitmap(img);
  stage.addChild(router);   
  pic.x = canvas.width - 90;
     (function(target) {
                pic.onMouseOver = function() {
                target.scaleX = target.scaleY = target.scale*1.2;
                update = true;
                }
     })(pic); 
   Ticker.addListener(window);

}
function tick() {
    if (update) {
        update = false; // only update once
        stage.update();
    }
}

</script>
<style>
 #div1, #div2
{
    float:left;
    width:100;
    height:150;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}

</style>
</head>

<body onLoad="init()">
<div id="div1">
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="150" ></canvas> 
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: first of all please have a look at your markup .. you've got two `body`tags in your markup

Comment: in the line `stage.addChild(router);` the argument `router` for the function is neither declared nor defined in the the program ..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to setup the stage to accept mouse events:

```
stage.enableMouseOver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [CSS3 scale transform](http://www.zenelements.com/blog/css3-transform/) instead of JavaScript to achieve this. Of course it would only work on browsers that support this feature, which may not be what you want.